# Netconsole won't start, says "wlan0 doesn't exist, aborting"

Tags: wireless

I'm trying to setup netconsole to debug a hard lock up, and I am running into a problem. I have the following config for netconsole:

```
options netconsole netconsole=6666@192.168.1.114/wlan0,6666@192.168.1.105/00:1e:d2:c4:72:54
```

During bootup I get the following spew:

```
[    5.256569] netconsole: local port 6666
[    5.256570] netconsole: local IP 192.168.1.114
[    5.256571] netconsole: interface wlan0
[    5.256572] netconsole: remote port 6666
[    5.256572] netconsole: remote IP 192.168.1.105
[    5.256573] netconsole: remote ethernet address 00:1e:d2:c4:72:54
[    5.256574] netconsole: wlan0 doesn't exist, aborting.
[    5.256575] netconsole: cleaning up
```

Not exactly sure what to do from here, any suggestions welcome.

**Edit** output of ip l for maco:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1f:bc:09:45:b5 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1f:bc:09:45:b6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
link/ether 00:14:6c:85:ad:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

**Edit** output of dmesg after modprobe error for kees:

```
[ 4557.261569] netconsole: local port 6666 
[ 4557.261573] netconsole: local IP 192.168.1.114
[ 4557.261576] netconsole: interface wlan0
[ 4557.261577] netconsole: remote port 6666
[ 4557.261580] netconsole: remote IP 192.168.1.105
[ 4557.261582] netconsole: remote ethernet address 00:1e:d2:c4:72:54
[ 4557.261585] netconsole: wlan0 doesn't support polling, aborting.
[ 4557.261587] netconsole: cleaning up
```

Comment: what's the output of `ip l` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
[ 4557.261585] netconsole: wlan0 doesn't support polling, aborting.
```

Netconsole needs a driver that supports polling which isn't the case with your wireless card. Could you try it with one of your Ethernet cards?

Answer (score 1):

If the `netconsole` module is loaded before the wireless network driver, it will not be able to find `wlan0` yet, since it doesn't exist. If your hard lock is later in the boot process, you can get the wireless driver loaded first, and the use `modprobe` to manually load `netconsole` next.

For example, boot normally, verify that `wlan0` is available (as you've done with `ip l`), then:

```
sudo modprobe netconsole netconsole=6666@192.168.1.114/wlan0,6666@192.168.1.105/00:1e:d2:c4:72:54
```

Comment: I get the following `Error inserting netconsole (/lib/modules/2.6.32-25-generic/kernel/drivers/net/netconsole.ko): Unknown error 524`

Comment: What does `dmesg` report when that happens?

Comment: I added the output to the question